# Перенести данные из def в if

Tags: python, функции, переменные, операторы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать перенос данных из функции?

```
def doing():
    what_do = input('What are u wanna do?')

if what_do == 'example': #Вот тут проблема, как мне перенести what_do из doing сюда?
    print('Anything')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`what_do` в данном случае локальная переменная функции `doing()`. Чтобы перенести ее в глобальную область видимости, из нее нужно вернуть значение.

```
def doing():
    return input('What are u wanna do?')

what_do = doing()
if what_do == 'example':
    print('Anything')
```

Answer (score 2):

Функция в программировании может возвращать значение, используя *return*.
Возвращенное значение можно сохранить в переменной, и затем использовать уже ее.

```
def doing():
    what_do = input('What are u wanna do?')
    return what_do


result = doing()
if result == 'example': 
    print('Anything')
```